# Use a non-newest git checkout in a buildout-based Plone site

Tags: git, plone, buildout

I have a buildout-based Plone site, with an productive and a development/test instance.  I noticed I currently have a problem building the development instance, and the difference which is likely to be related to the problem is different versions of a product which is "developed" in both instances.

Unfortunately the older version is the one which works ... so I tried to reset that package to the older revision and rebuild:

```
cd /path/to/my/instance
. bin/activate
cd src/plone.formwidget.recaptcha/
git checkout a0c334406c0d991f4facedce0334ab5566729b2f
cd -
bin/buildout buildout:newest=false
```

Unfortunately, `buildout` tries to pull, and fails:

```
mr.developer: git pull of 'plone.formwidget.recaptcha' failed.
mr.developer: You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
mr.developer: branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.
mr.developer:
mr.developer:     git pull <remote> <branch>
mr.developer:
mr.developer:
```

Well, I don't want a `git pull` to occur; so I looked for mr.developer options to help and added `mr.developer:auto-checkout=` to the command line.

There is still that `git pull`. How can I suppress it? And what would be the recommended way to pin the package to the desired revision?

Comment: Btw I avoid using checked out eggs in production - better to release your own internal version using e.g. jarn.mkrelease

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [mr.developer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) you can fix a checkout to a fixed revision:

```
my.package = git git://some.url.git rev=abcdef
```

With this `my.package` will always be pointint to `abcdef`, which can be either a branch or a revision sha.

For other version control systems, see mr.developer docs.

Comment: Since I use mr.develover (as was obvious from the question) and the project is organized by buildout scripts, this is the best solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with your build process, but you can make a simple hack to prevent pull from failing.

```
git checkout -b temp a0c334406c0d991f4facedce0334ab5566729b2f
git branch temp2 temp
git branch --set-upstream-to=temp2 temp
```

Since both branches are pointing to the same place you will have any issues.

**Caveat**
If you need to do this again, you will need to redo the two fake branches. It is probably easier to just delete them (which should be done when you are done anyway.)

```
git branch -D temp temp2
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. The problem is: now buildout fails for another package, and if I repeat this, I'll have several such cases spread over my project which can't be listed easily by one command ...